# What is the reason this flight is not available? CMB to ZRH direct

Tags: air-travel, bookings, routes

I'm using flightconnections to build a route and I can see that there is a CMB (Colombo, Sri Lanka) to ZRH (Zürich, Switzerland) direct flight in February. However, when I search for actual tickets, no one seems to have them.

After googling, I think it's part of the Week 65 flight, it looks like these routes were planned before coronavirus back in April 2020. Are these routes planned years ahead? Perhaps it was cancelled due to COVID-19, but maybe it is restarting since flightconnections seems to show availability in February 2021?

Comment: I suspect flightconnections.com's data is not up-to-date. Google Flights, for example, shows no direct flights CMB > ZRH in February 2021. I do not understand the meaning of  "...part of the Week 65 flight..."

Comment: Airlines generally adjust their schedule at least twice a year, sometimes more often (that's how it was when I did a short stint in an airline (in the 1990s) working in the group that produced the schedule).  I imagine that COVID and better software has made it, um, more interesting.  Airlines are continually trying to maximize the money that can be made from their product.  These days I would not be surprised if the schedule is changed every month.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears that FlightConnections' information is out of date.  The only carrier they list operating flights from CMB-ZRH is Edelweiss Air, a vacation-oriented carrier based in Zurich.  Currently Edelweiss Air will sell you a flight from CMB–ZRH or vice versa [in March or April 2021](https://www.flyedelweiss.com/EN/fly/flight-information/timetable/Pages/colombo.aspx) (or in winter '21-'22, which lends credence to your suspicion that these flights are announced long in advance.)

Edelweiss's [cancelled flights page](https://www.flyedelweiss.com/EN/alerts/Pages/corona-cancelled-flights.aspx) notes that their flights between CMB and ZRH have been cancelled between the dates of October 31, 2020 and March 12, 2021.  However, [the Internet Archive version of the same page from December 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20201224172127/https://www.flyedelweiss.com/EN/alerts/Pages/corona-cancelled-flights.aspx)<sup>1</sup> shows that the CMB–ZRH flights were only cancelled until January 31, 2021 at that time.  It seems likely that when Edelweiss made the previous announcement, they were hoping that demand might recover by the end of January;  but now they don't think that it will until March at the earliest.  (And to be honest, this also makes me skeptical that they will operate the flights they've scheduled in March or April.)

---

<sup>1</sup> I had to go poking around in the source code of the Internet Archive page linked above to extract the dates of cancellation.  Whatever CSS mojo that displays or collapses the sections of the table doesn't work properly via the Internet Archive version, but the information is still in the source code.

Comment: Edelweiss not only struggles with demand, it's also the ever-changing covid restrictions of switzerland (and other countries) that render most destinations impractical - especially for a vacation-oriented carrier. They are now basically in deep sleep, operating only enough to keep a few pilot licenses valid

Comment: That's true, but that's the case for most airlines, not only Edelweiss.